Mapbox Android: How to render shapefile as vector layer from .zip file stored locally in mobile device?
I just started learning mobile development for Android and I am trying to create an GIS that work offline. Currently, I am struggling to create a vector file using a zipped shapefile that is stored locally in my device.
My Attempt:
I tried using Mapbox Studio and importing the shapefile to my custom map style as a datasets and it worked when I used the style's URL in my app. Considering that creating a vector tile that conforms to the Mapbox Vector Tile during runtime might be difficult, I am currently trying to convert the shapefile into a GeoJSON and then passing it as a Symbol Layer.
Below is my current MainActivity.kt file
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import com.example.kmtsaplingmap.utils.LocationPermissionHelper
import com.mapbox.android.gestures.MoveGestureDetector
import com.mapbox.maps.CameraOptions
import com.mapbox.maps.ImageHolder
import com.mapbox.maps.MapView
import com.mapbox.maps.Style
import com.mapbox.maps.extension.style.expressions.dsl.generated.interpolate
import com.mapbox.maps.extension.style.sources.generated.vectorSource
import com.mapbox.maps.extension.style.style
import com.mapbox.maps.plugin.LocationPuck2D
import com.mapbox.maps.plugin.PuckBearing
import com.mapbox.maps.plugin.gestures.OnMoveListener
import com.mapbox.maps.plugin.gestures.gestures
import com.mapbox.maps.plugin.locationcomponent.OnIndicatorBearingChangedListener
import com.mapbox.maps.plugin.locationcomponent.OnIndicatorPositionChangedListener
import com.mapbox.maps.plugin.locationcomponent.location
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private lateinit var mapView: MapView
    private lateinit var locationPermissionHelper: LocationPermissionHelper
    private val onIndicatorBearingChangedListener = OnIndicatorBearingChangedListener {
        mapView.mapboxMap.setCamera(CameraOptions.Builder().bearing(it).build())
    }
    private val onIndicatorPositionChangedListener = OnIndicatorPositionChangedListener {
        mapView.mapboxMap.setCamera(CameraOptions.Builder().center(it).build())
        mapView.gestures.focalPoint = mapView.mapboxMap.pixelForCoordinate(it)
    }
    private val onMoveListener = object : OnMoveListener {
        override fun onMoveBegin(detector: MoveGestureDetector) {
            onCameraTrackingDismissed()
        }
        override fun onMove(detector: MoveGestureDetector): Boolean {
            return false
        }
        override fun onMoveEnd(detector: MoveGestureDetector) {}
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        // Create a map programmatically and set the initial camera
        mapView = MapView(this)

        // Add the map view to the activity (you can also add it to other views as a child)
        setContentView(mapView)

        // Handle permission for accessing user's location
        locationPermissionHelper = LocationPermissionHelper(WeakReference(this))
        locationPermissionHelper.checkPermissions {
            onMapReady()
        }
    }

    private fun onMapReady() {
        mapView.mapboxMap.setCamera(
            CameraOptions.Builder()
                .zoom(14.0)
                .build()
        )

        mapView.mapboxMap.loadStyle(
            // Will render a vector layer when using Mapbox Studio Style URL that included the shapefile's datasets
            style(style = Style.OUTDOORS) {
                // TODO: render locally saved shapefile
                +vectorSource("local shapefile") {
                    url("asset://test.zip")
                }
            }
        ) { style ->
            initLocationComponent()
            setupGesturesListener()
        }
    }

    private fun setupGesturesListener() {
        mapView.gestures.addOnMoveListener(onMoveListener)
    }

    @SuppressLint("IncorrectNumberOfArgumentsInExpression")
    private fun initLocationComponent() {
        val locationComponentPlugin = mapView.location
        locationComponentPlugin.updateSettings {
            puckBearing = PuckBearing.HEADING
            puckBearingEnabled = true
            enabled = true
            locationPuck = LocationPuck2D(
                bearingImage = ImageHolder.from(R.drawable.mapbox_user_puck_icon),
                shadowImage = ImageHolder.from(R.drawable.mapbox_user_icon_shadow),
                scaleExpression = interpolate {
                    linear()
                    zoom()
                    stop {
                        literal(0.0)
                        literal(0.6)
                    }
                    stop {
                        literal(20.0)
                        literal(1.0)
                    }
                }.toJson()
            )
        }
        locationComponentPlugin.addOnIndicatorPositionChangedListener(onIndicatorPositionChangedListener)
        locationComponentPlugin.addOnIndicatorBearingChangedListener(onIndicatorBearingChangedListener)
    }

    private fun onCameraTrackingDismissed() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onCameraTrackingDismissed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        mapView.location
            .removeOnIndicatorPositionChangedListener(onIndicatorPositionChangedListener)
        mapView.location
            .removeOnIndicatorBearingChangedListener(onIndicatorBearingChangedListener)
        mapView.gestures.removeOnMoveListener(onMoveListener)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        mapView.location
            .removeOnIndicatorBearingChangedListener(onIndicatorBearingChangedListener)
        mapView.location
            .removeOnIndicatorPositionChangedListener(onIndicatorPositionChangedListener)
        mapView.gestures.removeOnMoveListener(onMoveListener)
    }
}


The only question I see is "is [it] possible to create an offline map using Jetpack Compose?" -- To which the answer is: "Yes". But you probably want to know something else. Can you please be more specific? Edit your question and provide the code you have so far with a concrete question which part of the code you have problems with. Please also see here for How to ask questions on Stack Overflow.

@Leviathan thank you for your feedback! I will edit my questions above.

After re-evaluating my code and questions, I came to realize that what is want to know is literally something else. So I changed the overall questions to explain the exact part that I am struggling with.
